# Caster wheel in Blender

Tags: rigging

[image]

Hello guys, I want to know how to fix the wheels' spin when moving towards ''X'' and ''Y'' directions... Right now it only spins when one direction is used(some one X axis and some on Y axis) or when rotating the Z axis. This is the only way I found to mimic a caster wheel in blender, but unfortunately with some issues.

If there is a known method to do it in another way, I would appreciate knowing.

Wheels file:
[image]